# Unable to set badge on chrome extension after opening tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, badge

I am writing a chrome extension which has a button on popup window. When the button is clicked, it fetches all text present on the page and finds the text containing the sub-string "***IP-***", appends that to a base url and opens that url in a new tab. Usually 8-10 tabs open.

This is working as expected.

However, after opening all tabs, I want the number of tabs opened in the process to be displayed as a badge on extension icon which I am not able to do.
Here is the code that I am using but no badge is displayed on the icon.

Not sure if it has something to do with the content of each tab being loaded.
If I place the code for setting a badge on a different place in my `popup.js` file and give it a hard-coded text, it works.

**EDIT - Added the working code**

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs=> {
   chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: tabs[0].id, allFrames: true},
      func: openlinks,
      })
    });
  })
  
})

function openlinks(){
   var all_text = document.body.innerText;
   all_text = all_text.split("\n")
   let counter = 0
   for(let i = 0; i < all_text.length; i++){
     if (all_text[i].includes("IP-")){
        counter++
        url = "base-url-goes-here"+all_text[i]
        window.open(url)
       }
   }
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage(counter)
}
```

**default_settings.js (service_worker)**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
    chrome.action.setBadgeText({text: request.toString()});
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "author": "Author Name",
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "scripting", "activeTab"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "default_settings.js"
      },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Title",
        "default_popup": "src/popup.html"
      },
    "manifest_version": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/
[...] content scripts can access the following chrome APIs directly:

```
i18n
storage
runtime:
    connect
    getManifest
    getURL
    id
    onConnect
    onMessage
    sendMessage
```

Content scripts are unable to access other APIs directly.

So you can't use chrome.action api in you injected script, but you can send that info (counter) with chrome.runtime.sendMessage

Comment: After reading your answer, I tried adding `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` snippet at the point in my code where the badge is being set and added the listener above where I am using `chrome.scripting.executeScript` but wasn't able to achieve the expected result because I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong.
Would you be able to provide code snippets?

Comment: edit your question adding the sendMessage() line and the runtime.onMessage listener in your service_worker script so we can see your progress.

Comment: Updated. Please have a look.

Comment: Update: Please ignore my previous comment.
Finally I was able to do it. I was adding `onMessage.addListener`in my `popup.js` code that's why it wasn't working. Adding it to service_worker like you said worked on the first attempt. I have updated my question above having the correct code. Thank you for your help.